# AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy' with Python 3.6.10 and Spyder 4.1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, spyder

I am attempting to run an environment I created (called TensorFlow) in Anaconda with Python 3.6.10 installed. The reason for this is I want to use Keras and TensorFlow, but Keras does not currently support Python 3.7 (to my knowledge). Spyder and Jupyter Notebooks both open on my base environment (with Python 3.7), but not on this one with Python 3.6. Below is the error I continue to run into:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3718, in main
mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3559, in run_spyder
main.setup()
File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 1010, in setup
from spyder.plugins.ipythonconsole.plugin import IPythonConsole
File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\plugin.py", line 26, in 
from qtconsole.client import QtKernelClient
File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\qtconsole\client.py", line 12, in 
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop, zmqstream
File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\__init__.py", line 3, in 
from zmq.eventloop.ioloop import IOLoop
File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 78, in 
while _IOLoop.configurable_default() is not _IOLoop:
File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 328, in configurable_default
from tornado.platform.asyncio import AsyncIOLoop
File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 34, in 
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy'
```

What I know:

- I've found elsewhere here and on GitHub that the current version of asyncio does not support Python 3.6, though my knowledge of the problems starts and ends there.

What I've tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling Spyder
- Creating a new environment and reinstalling Spyder and Jupyer Notebooks there

What worked:

- I upgraded to Python 3.7 in the TensorFlow environment, and was then able to launch Spyder and Jupyter Notebooks. I then downgraded to Python 3.6 again, and was unable to open for the reasons previously stated.

Apologies if this issue seems basic. Any help is appreciated.